# Should .podspec file be committed?

Tags: git, version-control, cocoapods

The `.podspec` file defines a pod. Its value `spec.source` is used to retrieve the actual code to build the pod, for example a Git repository.

```
spec.source = { :git => "https://github.com/me/myrepo.git", :tag => "v1.0.2" }
```

Should the `.podspec` itself be present in the repository?

I suppose the `.podspec` does not need itself to build the pod (it's a recipe for the pod, not an ingredient) but maybe it's considered a good practice to keep it in version control for some reasons.